# Open another application with angularjs Android

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, steroids, supersonic

Is there a way to open another application with angularJs on steroids? 
I wanna open the default gps navigator of the system passing it the latitude and the longitude of the starting and the destination location from my own application.

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you want to to programmatically or through a ui-click?

How about using a  tag with the geo-prefix like this?

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">open map</a>
```

Or use steroids.openURL()

```
steroids.openURL("geo:38.897096,-77.036545");
```

As described here: 
http://docs.appgyver.com/en/edge/steroids_Steroids%20App%20and%20Device_steroids.openURL.md.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and I'll let you know.

Comment: How did it go? Please accept if it solved your problem.